# Was my computer hacked? My outgoing mail IP was temporarily from Russia

Tags: email, gmail

I got a bounce message today from a client. In the bounce notice it shows:

```
The error that the other server returned was: 
554-Service unavailable; Client host [mail-io0-f178.google.com] blocked using 
554-Barracuda Reputation; 
554 http://www.barracudanetworks.com/reputation/?r=1&ip=38.116.199.194
```

And further down where it shows the original message it says

```
Received: from Macbook-Pro-Retina.local ([38.116.199.194])
```

The above is a blocked Russian IP Address. Normally the source of my messages shows:

```
Received: from Macbook-Pro-Retina.local
 (CPE0016cbc430da-CMf0f249004a80.cpe.net.cable.rogers.com. [174.119.**.**])
```

The 174.119 is my normal external IP address and shows in the source of any message I send. Also I use Google apps for all my mail so its going through their server.

So the question is, is the bounce message a result of an issue on my local machine or does it have to do with the client's server?

Comment: This question is somewhat off-topic for StackOverflow, as it doesn't pertain to programming at all.  Try SuperUser.

Answer (score 1):

`38.116.199.194` IP address is part of a `38.0.0.0 - 38.255.255.255` range allocated to Cogent ([ARIN WHOIS](http://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-38-112-0-0-1/pft?s=38.116.199.194)). A part of this range, `38.116.198.0/23` subnet is operated by [MaRS Discovery District](https://www.marsdd.com/).
It appears that your computer was connected to the MaRS Discovery District's network when you sent the email. Maybe you were using their Wifi at the time or maybe some (malicious) software on your machine was routing traffic via that network unbeknownst to you.

Comment: Thanks Serge. You are correct. I have an office at MaRS. Much appreciated!